# file not found exception web service

Tags: web-service, exceção, maven

eu tenho uma aplicação web e mobile que são alimentados pelo web service o problema que toda vez que estou tentando recuperar um usuário eu recebo a seguinte mensagem "java.io.filenotfoundexception"(seguida da minha URL) e o código de resposta 404. Eu já procurei em tudo e não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar. estou fazendo o projeto pelo MAVEN e não sei se esta faltando alguma dependência ou não ( pelo menos não aparece nenhum erro com relação a isso, mas vou deixar o pom.xml para vocês olharem). alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

ps: o processo chega no "int code = connection.getResponseCode();" e não vai para o web service como deveria

esse código se refere ao meu main que eu estou usando como teste

```
String nome ;
    String email;
    String senha;
    long codigo = 2;
        URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/WebServiceMavenDivulgueAqui/webresources/webService/usuario/recuperarPorId?id="+codigo);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code);

        InputStream inputStrem = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStrem));

        String a;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((a  = br.readLine()) != null){
         //a += br.readLine();
         stringBuilder.append(a);
        }
      //  System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        connection.disconnect();

         JSONObject jsonObject;

         JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();  

        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringBuilder.toString());

        codigo = (long) jsonObject.get("codigo");
        nome = (String) jsonObject.get("nome");
        email = (String) jsonObject.get("email");
        senha = (String) jsonObject.get("senha");

        System.out.println("o codigo é :" + codigo + " nome : " + nome 
        + " email : " + email + " senha : " + senha);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro de URLException conexao ao rest ( recuperar usuario)\n" + ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro de IOException conexao ao rest ( Recuperar usuario) \n" + ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro de ParseException conexao ao rest ( Recuperar usuario) \n" + ex);
    }
```

esse código se refere ao método no web service

```
 @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("usuario/recuperarPorId")
public String recuperarUsuarioPorId(@QueryParam("id") Long json){

    UsuarioDao u = new UsuarioDao();
    BeansUsuario mod = new BeansUsuario();

    mod.setPesquisarPorId(json);
    mod = u.buscarPorId(mod);

    Gson g = new Gson();
    return g.toJson(mod);
}
```

e essas são as minhas dependências no pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Java mesmo, certo? Não é outra linguagem obscura que usa a JVM por baixo?

Comment: Já tentou `http://localhost:8084/usuario/recuperarPorId?id=12`? Ou outras variações da URL?, com menos campos?

Comment: desse mesmo jeito que você colocou ai não, mas já tentei com menos campos

Comment: Posso não ter a resposta definitiva, mas posso sugerir algumas detecções de problema; preciso chegar no meu computador e testar um pouco

Comment: eu consegui aqui! não sei ao certo mas acho que foi alguma dependência do maven que estava faltando

Comment: Ótimo! Coloca na pergunta o que você acha que fez que resolveu, aí outra pessoa que tenha a mesma dúvida vai saber para onde ir

Answer (score 0):

eu acho que resolveu quando eu adicionei esses códigos no pom.xml

```
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```